# DataBinding showing null value on first remote call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-mvvm

In my app, i have a fragment that call a remote service for get user profile information and show it, and I've used DataBinding for show data.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.myapp.ProfileViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.profile.firstName+ ' '+ viewModel.profile.lastName}" />

            <!-- Other textviews -->

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

this is ProfileViewModel class

```
class ProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var profileRepository: ProfileRepository

    private var _profile = MutableLiveData<Profile>()
    val profile: LiveData<Profile>
        get() = _profile

    fun getProfile(token: String) {
        profileRepository.profile(
            token,
            {
                // success
                _profile.value = it.value
            },
            {
               //error
            }
        )
    }
}

data class Profile(
    firstName : String,
    lastName : String,
    // other fields
)
```

And this is fragment where profile should be showed:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentProfileBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: ProfileViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_profile,
            container,
            false
        )

        viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)[ProfileViewModel::class.java]
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.getProfile(
            "aToken"
        )
    }
}
```

Now it happen that first time i open fragment, repository call service and get data correctly, but "null" is showed inside textviews. If i close fragment and i reopen it, edittext are populate correctly. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Use `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` to let view handle runtime changes of `LiveData`

Answer (score 1):

Set binding.lifecycleOwner in your fragment class in order for updates in LiveData objects to be reflected in corresponding views. Your fragment class should look like this:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentProfileBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: ProfileViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_profile,
            container,
            false
        )

        viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)[ProfileViewModel::class.java]
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

        binding.viewModel = viewModel 

        //add lifecycleOwner
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.getProfile(
            "aToken"
        )
    }
}
```